# Custom event pattern for AWS event bridge

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I am trying to add a rule using below code

```
const rule = new Rule(this, 'rule', {
        eventBus: bus,
        eventPattern: {
            "message_data": {
                "type": [{ 'equals-ignore-case': 'customer_' }],
            },
        },
        ruleName: `${stackId}-rule`,
    });
```

my JSON event:

```
{

"message_data":{
  "id": "2779e723-dadc-48fe-9a2b-291874cd4463",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "customer"
  }
}
```

When I trying to deploy. It is failing with error

```
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'message_data' does not exist in type 'EventPattern'.
```

Any inputs?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html), `eventPattern` must adhere to the [EventPattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.EventPattern.html) interface. `message_data` is not a property of that interface. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve here, but this will likely remediate that specific error.

```
const rule = new Rule(this, 'rule', {
  eventBus: bus,
  eventPattern: {
    detail: {
      "message_data": {
        "type": [{ 'equals-ignore-case': 'customer_' }],
      },
    },
  },
  ruleName: `${stackId}-rule`,
});
```